# How can I use React Hooks to refresh a table when a row is deleted or added?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have a react-table component that displays some game data.

The component uses hooks to set state like this:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    gameData(false).then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, []);
```

Inside my table, I have a button that adds or removes a row via a Put request to an api.

I want it to remove the row without doing a full/visable page refresh.

Here is the bit of code that does the axios put request.

You can see I'm trying to use 'setData' again to 'refresh' the data.

But that doesn't work. Now it does remove the row, but I can only see that after I hit f5 or hit the browser refresh button.

```
const updateGame = async (game, action) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    game.isApproved = action;
    axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/games/" + game.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(game),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
    // trying to refresh table after the axios Put request
    setData(data);
};
```

Is there a way to refresh state dynamically without having to hit refresh?

Thanks!

Comment: can you include codesandox link or any online  IDE

Comment: Have you tried putting this at the end of the delete function `setData(data.filter(data => data.id !== id));` ?
With the id being the identifier of what you deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to let the effect know when you want it to run. The empty bracket is basically like using onMount so by adding the data to it will refresh when data is changed.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    gameData(false).then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, [data]);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was so simple!  I didn't even know I was missing that part.

Answer (score 1):

```
setData(data);
```

This just sets the data you already have because the `data` variable hasn't changed.

Did you mean to set the new data returned by your PUT request? If so you need to `await` the request, and then set the new state.

You probably want something like:

```
const newData = await axios({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "api/games/" + game.id,
    data: JSON.stringify(game),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
});
setData(newData);
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the const newData and used that in setState.  But I got a lot of errors inside /hooks/useTable.js.  The top error is TypeError: data.map is not a function and it's in some react source code file: src/hooks/useTable.js:215 in something called useMemo

Comment: Check if the object that you are importing into data is correct.